# Tooltip in gridview using dictionary method

Tags: c#, gridview, dictionary, tooltip

Evening all.

I have the following code that I need looking into - basically I'm clutching at straws here. I have a gridview that I would like to assign tooltips to.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctl in cell.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctl.GetType().ToString().Contains("DataControlLinkButton"))
                    {
                        Dictionary<String, String> headerTooltips = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                        headerTooltips["Product ID"] = "A unique product ID";
                        headerTooltips["Product Description"] = "Description of product";

                        String headerText = cell.Text; 
                        cell.Attributes.Add("title", headerTooltips[headerText]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is a tool tip that appears by each column heading (i.e. Product ID and Product Description.)

However, when I use the above code, I receive the following error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary." This appears on the

```
cell.Attributes.Add("title", headerTooltips[headerText]);
```

line.

Can someone point out the error in my ways? Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: You say that you want to display the tooltips on the header row, but your code suggests that you are going to use the tooltips to show product details etc. So if a specific product corresponds to the header row, what data is contained in the actual rows of the grid? Are you sure you don't want tooltips on the cells of the data rows rather than on the header?

Comment: Hello Anders - no definitely the tooltips on the header row. I used product ID and description as examples, in reality they would be coded which would mean little to the user and therefore I would like to assign a tool tip to each of the column headings to explain what that heading actually is...apologies for the confusion.

It is probably just very bad code I have attempted to adapt in my novice manner. If you can think of an alternative to achieve this task, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because you haven't added an entry to your dictionary that corresponds to the value of cell.Text. The only keys your dictionary contains is 'Product ID' and 'Product Description' so unless you have cells that actually contain this text it will always fail. You could do this:

```
if (headerTooltips.ContainsKey(headerText))
{
    cell.Attributes.Add("title", headerTooltips[headerText]);
}
```

Which gets you beyond the exception but don't think it does what you are trying to accomplish.

**Edit:**

Do you just want the cell.Text to show up as the tooltip? If yes then do this:

```
// This is only replacing the foreach part, the rest of your code is still valid
foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctl in cell.Controls)
{
    if (ctl.GetType().ToString().Contains("DataControlLinkButton"))
    {
        cell.Attributes.Add("title", cell.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cory, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it with Product ID (in replace of title) and the same message appears.

Not to worry too much, thank you for your input.